# Accessing to a dataset value using C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, dataset

I have a application that calls a web service where GetDataSourceMappingTable its a data structure its a `data set`.

What I am trying to do its to extract the value of a certain column (Users_Tests) which will give me the mandatory parameter to be able to call another web service `GetUser()`.

Here you have data set structure:

```
GetDataTableResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetDataTableResult>
            <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
               <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                  <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="Table">
                           <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                 <xs:element name="SourceID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="Caption" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                           </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                     </xs:choice>
                  </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
```

I need to call the element name `"Caption"` and pass the value `Users_Test` (where Users_Test its a value inside that table) to get the `SourceID e.g. "Data1"`

Here is my code so far:

```
var ds = proxy.GetDataTable();
var DataSourceId = ds.Tables["Table"].Select("Caption = 'Users_test'");

UserData[] userDataId = client.GetUser(ref apiKey, ref message, DataSourceId.ToString()); //GetUserData need the sourceID e.g. Data1 to be able to be used
```

Whenever I run the program in the DataSourceId variable inside `GetUser()` method is not being passed correctly. I get an array 0 and 1. In 0 I get Data1 and in 1 I get Users_tests.

I am suppose to get e.g. "Data1"

How I can only get the value of the Caption but give the `SourceID` to the `GetUser()` method?

As well I would like to be able to have multiple captions such us (`Select("Caption = 'Users_test'");` and `Select("Caption = 'Users_test1'");` and `Select("Caption = 'Users_test3'");`

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DataTable.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a `DataRow[]` array, so you can use the Linq [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to project the rows to the entry for `Caption`.  The following expression gets the `SourceID` value corresponding to your caption, returns `null` if not found, and throws an exception on multiple matches:

```
    var DataSourceId = ds.Tables["Table"]
        .Select("Caption = 'Users_test'") // Find rows with Caption = 'Users_test'
        .Select(r => r["SourceID"])       // Project to the value of SourceId
        .Where(s => s != DBNull.Value)    // Filter DBNull (might occur when the SourceID cell is missing
        .Select(s => s.ToString())        // Project to string value
        .SingleOrDefault();               // null if no matches, throw an exception if more than one match.
```

If you might reasonably expect more than one row with `Caption = 'Users_test'`, you can loop through them all with a `foreach` statement:

```
    var query = ds.Tables["Table"]
        .Select("Caption = 'Users_test'") // Find rows with Caption = 'Users_test'
        .Select(r => r["SourceID"])       // Project to the value of SourceId
        .Where(s => s != DBNull.Value)    // Filter DBNull (might occur when the SourceID cell is missing
        .Select(s => s.ToString());        // Project to string value
    foreach (var DataSourceId in query)
    {
    }
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/phEwIp).

**Update**

To select multiple captions with `DataTable.Select()`, use the `OR` operator:

```
            var query = ds.Tables["Table"]
                .Select("Caption = 'Users_test' OR Caption = 'Users_test3'") // Find rows any of several captions
                .Select(r => r["SourceID"])       // Project to the value of SourceId
                .Where(s => s != DBNull.Value)    // Filter DBNull (might occur when the SourceID cell is missing
                .Select(s => s.ToString());       // Project to string value
```

Comment: Excellent solution! thanks a lot It worked perfect (the first one)

Comment: Can you please tell me if I have more than caption that I want to add to add (e.g. Users_Test1, Users_Test2, and so on) How I can do it? thanks

Comment: @Aarancibia - I'm not sure what you want just from that comment.  Suggest you might want to edit your question to provide a [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you want to do.  Or ask another question, as the preferred format here is [one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Comment: Sorry you are right, my apologies. I have edited the question. Its in the last sentence. Thanks again